# ng-if not working after clicking "Save Changes" button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update information clicking on edit change button. After updating the information, I want the updated information to be shown by hiding the form, when I click on Save Changes button. My api is working and information is getting updated.But `ng-if` is not working after clicking Save Changes button.

#### info.html file

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-if="userEnteredInfo">
    <div class="form-group">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal form-info-table">
            <dt>First Name:</dt>
            <dd>{{user.basicInfo.firstName}}
            </dd>
            <dt>Last Name:</dt>
            <dd>{{user.basicInfo.lastName}}</dd>
            <dt>Status:</dt>
            <dd>{{user.basicInfo.status}}</dd>
            <dt>Work Location:</dt>
            <dd>{{user.basicInfo.workLocation}}</dd>               
            <dt>Date of Birth:</dt>
            <dd>{{user.basicInfo.dateOfBirth}}</dd>
            <dt>Title:</dt>
            <dd>{{user.basicInfo.title}}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="panel-body form-panel-box" ng-if="makeChanges" ng-submit="saveChanges(user)">
    <form class="form-horizontal edit-changes-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" ng-model="user.basicInfo.firstName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastName">Last Name:
              </label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" ng-
                 model="user.basicInfo.lastName"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="status">Status:
               </label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" ng-
                   model="user.basicInfo.status">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Work Location">Work 
               Location:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="work" ng-
                  model="user.basicInfo.location">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="dateOfBirth">Date of 
              Birth</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateOfBirth" ng-
                  model="user.basicInfo.dateOfBirth">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text/number" class="form-control" id="title" 
                  ng-model="user.basicInfo.title">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save 
                 Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

#### info.js file

```
app.controller('info',function($scope,$localStorage,authService,$http){
      $scope.user = $localStorage.userObject;

      $scope.userEnteredInfo = true;
      $scope.editChanges = function(){
        $scope.makeChanges = true;
        $scope.userEnteredInfo= false;

    }
    //Edit changes for updating information//
    $scope.saveChanges = function(userData){
        $scope.updatedInfoDetails = {
            firstName: userData.basicInfo.firstName,
            lastName: userData.basicInfo.lastName,
            status: userData.basicInfo.status,
            WorkLocation: userData.basicInfo.location,
            dateOfBirth: userData.basicInfo.dateOfBirth,
            title: userData.basicInfo.title
        }

    authService.postUpdatedInfo($scope.updatedInfoDetails)
    .then(function(response){
        if(response.status == 200){
             $scope.updatedInfo = "You have successfully updated the changes";

            };
        });
        $scope.userEnteredInfo = false;
        $scope.makeChanges = true;
        console.log("success");

    };
});
```

#### authService.js file

```
app.service('authService', function($localStorage,$http) {
    this.postUpdatedInfo = function(userChangedInfo){
        console.log('the user data is: ', userChangedInfo);
        var urlForChangingInfo = "/api/users/" + $localStorage.getUserId;
        return $http({
            method:'PUT',
            url:urlForChangingInfo,
            data:userChangedInfo,
            headers:{"x-access-token":$localStorage.authToken}
        });
    };    
});
```

Comment: makeChanges is always true

Comment: Which `ng-if` has the problem? And what is it doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

makeChanges is never made to false,

try this,

```
authService.postUpdatedInfo($scope.updatedInfoDetails)
.then(function(response){
    if(response.status == 200){
         $scope.updatedInfo = "You have successfully updated the changes";

        };
    });
    $scope.userEnteredInfo = false;
    $scope.makeChanges = false;
    console.log("success");

};
```

Comment: what if you got 0 or 500 or 400 series status code? try to implement both promises, success and error

Answer (score 0):

you are never setting `$scope.userEnteredInfo` to `true` , can you try code given below :

```
authService.postUpdatedInfo($scope.updatedInfoDetails)
.then(function(response){
    if(response.status == 200){
         $scope.updatedInfo = "You have successfully updated the changes";
         $scope.userEnteredInfo = true;//set true here
         $scope.makeChanges = true;
         console.log("success");
        }
        else
        {
         // error if response  status other than 200
         $scope.userEnteredInfo = false;
         $scope.makeChanges = false;
         console.log("error");
        };
    });


};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working. I guess it's a silly mistake.

Comment: Glad to be able to help, please mark as the answer if i helped you solve the problem.